# Why does VS Code PowerShell terminal map a new drive?

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code, powershell-5.0, powershell-7.0

I was making a PowerShell script in Visual Studio Code that used the command `Get-PSDrive`, and to my surprise, it seemed like while using VS Code, a new drive identical to my `C:\` drive called `Temp` appeared.

[image: Fig 1.1]

I was taken aback by this result as as far as I knew, I only had 2 other drives besides my main `C:\` drive connected. I tried to replicate this on other terminals with no success except for PowerShell 7:

[image: Fig 1.2]
<sub>Windows Terminal PowerShell 5.1</sub>

[image: Fig 1.3]
<sub>PowerShell 5.1</sub>

[image: Fig 1.4]
<sub>PowerShell 5.1 (86x)</sub>

[image: Fig 1.5]
<sub>PowerShell 7 (86x)</sub>

[image: Fig 1.6]
<sub>Windows Terminal PowerShell 7</sub>

---

As I saw that it was replicated by PwSh 7, I decided to check the versions of each of the PowerShells with the `$host` variable and I saw something even more unexpected:

```
Version          : 5.1.19041.1
```

<sub>Windows Terminal PowerShell 5.1</sub>

```
Version          : 5.1.19041.1
```

<sub>PowerShell 5.1</sub>

```
Version          : 5.1.19041.1
```

<sub>PowerShell 5.1 (86x)</sub>

```
Version          : 7.0.2
```

<sub>PowerShell 7 (86x)</sub>

```
Version          : 7.0.2
```

<sub>Windows Terminal PowerShell 7</sub>

which all seemed normal, but when I checked the VSCode `$host`, I got the result

```
Version          : 2020.6.0
```

What is causing the differences in the outputs of

```
Get-PSDrive | Where-Object {$_.Provider.Name -eq "FileSystem"}
```

between PwSh 7, PowerShell 5.1, and VS Code PwSh?

Comment: the `$Host` variable is NOT necessarily the version of PoSh/Pwsh. it's the host/console info and is _usually_ the ps version. you may want to cross-check the `.Version` with the `.Name`. ///// my PS7 install shows that `Temp:` drive in the console AND in the VSCode console. i presume it is something that PS7 does by default. i suspect it is a convenience feature to deal with different ways to find the OS/user temp dir.

Comment: I took this from the `Version` section in the `$host` variable

Comment: yep, and that is not _always_ the PoSh/Pwsh version number. _sometimes_ it will be the just the console host version. you are safer to use `$PSVersionTable` for the PS version.

Comment: according to this >>> Provide a platform-agnostic way to determine the temp. directory, e.g., via an automatic variable. · Issue #4216 · PowerShell/PowerShell — https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4216 <<< it seems to be something added with ps7 to give coders a consistent way to find the actual temp dir.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That `Temp:` drive is not "a new drive identical to my `C:\` drive"; its `Root` is `$Env:Temp`, not `C:\`.

According to [PowerShell Team May 2020 Update](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/powershell-team-may-2020-update/#user-content-new-experimental-feature), which actually describes PowerShell 7.1, this was added in PowerShell 7.0...

> In PowerShell 7.0, we added a `temp:` PSDrive. This works on all platforms and automatically maps to your user temporary path.

By the way, the command you used to make those screenshots could be simplified to `Get-PSDrive -PSProvider FileSystem`.